# Counterexample for using Dynkin($\pi-\lambda$) theorem in the proof of Fubini's theorem for a not $\sigma-$finite space

Tags: measure-theory

A famous counterexample for Fubini's theorem not working in a not $\sigma-$finite space is the product space of $(X, \mathcal{M}) = (Y, \mathcal{N}) = ([0, 1], \mathcal{B}([0, 1]))$
with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $X$, counting measure $c$ on $Y$ and $f = \chi_{D}$ where $D = \{(x, x): x \in [0, 1]\}$.

On the other hand, I was considering a proof of the following theorem, which is often considered before proving Fubini's theorem:

> For any $E \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$, the functions $f: x \mapsto c(E_x)$ and $g: y \mapsto \lambda(E^y)$ ($E_x, E^y$ are
> sections of $E$) are measurable with respect to $\mathcal{M}$ (and
> $\mathcal{N}$, respectively) and $\int_X g dc = \int_Y f d\lambda$.

Trying to prove the theorem using $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, it seems that(I have not rigorously checked, so actually there might be a wrong part in the statements below)

1. The collection of measurable rectangles in $X \times Y$ is a $\pi-$system.
2. If $D$ is the collection of all elements in $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ for which the theorem holds, $X \times Y \in D$ and for disjoint $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq D$, $\cup_n E_n \in D$.

If these are true, the part that does not work for $D$ to be a $\lambda-$system should be $E \in D \Rightarrow E^C \in D$. What can be a counterexample for such set $E$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have too many things called $D$, let's let $\Delta = \{(x,x) : x \in [0,1]\}$ denote the diagonal.  Then $E = \Delta^C$ is your counterexample.

We have $E_x = [0,1] \setminus \{x\}$ whose counting measure is infinite.  So $f \equiv \infty$, which is measurable because constant, and $\int_X f\,d\lambda = \int \infty \,d\lambda = \infty$.  Likewise, $E^y = [0,1] \setminus \{y\}$ whose Lebesgue measure is 1.  So $g \equiv 1$, which is again measurable because constant, and $\int_Y g\,dc = \int 1\,dc = \infty$.

So the theorem holds for $E$.  But it clearly does not hold for $E^C = \Delta$.

Comment: Thanks! Right after posting the question I realized that this counterexample (which I somehow stated in the question) actually works.